# How correctly show video with transparency in Qt with OpenCV + FFMpeg

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to show a video with transparency in a Qt6 application using OpenCV + FFMPEG.
Actually those are tool versions:

- Win 11
- Qt 6.3.0
- OpenCV 4.5.5 (built with CMake)
- FFMPEG 2022-04-03-git-1291568c98-full_build-www.gyan.dev

I've used a base .mov video with transparency as test (link provided below).
First of all I've converted .mov video to .webm video (VP9) and I see in output text that alpha channel remains

> ffmpeg -i '.\Retro Bars.mov' -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 output.webm

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2,
    ...
    Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), argb(progressive),
    ...

Output #0, webm, 
   ...
   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9, yuva420p(tv, progressive),
   ...
```

But when I show info of output file with ffmpeg it loses alpha channel:

> ffmpeg -i .\output.webm

```
Input #0, matroska,webm,
    ...
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, progressive),
    ...
```

If I open output.webm with OBS it is shown correctly without a background, as shown in picture:
[image: obs_load]

If I try to open it with OpenCV + FFMPEG it shows a black background under bars, as shown in picture:
[image: Qt_out]

This is how I load video in Qt:

```cpp
cv::VideoCapture capture;
capture.open(filename, cv::CAP_FFMPEG);
capture.set(cv::CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, false); // try forcing load alpha channel
... //in a thread
while (capture.read(frame)) {
    qDebug() << "c" << frame.channels() << "t" <<  frame.type() << "d" <<  frame.depth(); // output: c 3 t 16 d 0
    cv::cvtColor(frame, frame, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGBA); //useless since no alpha channel is detected
    img = QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
    emit processedImage(img); // to show image in a QLabel with QPixmap::fromImage(img)
}
```

I think the problem is when I load the video with OpenCV, it doens't detect alpha channel, since I can load correctly in other player (obs, html5, etc.)

What I'm wrong with all process to show this video in Qt with transparency?

EDIT: Added dropbox link with test video + ffmpeg outputs:
[sample items](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mljnqgy1o9cg16u/AAD68pphswiiia_0TuqKldIqa?dl=0)

Comment: Does [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8468) help?

Comment: Well since I'm using OpenCV that uses FFmpeg as back-end I can't use that functions, that would be nice to know how force FFmpeg codec with OpenCV and use libvpx-vp9

Comment: I don't think it is possible to capture RGBA (or yuva420p) format using OpenCV with FFmpeg backend (unless video is uncompressed). Are you looking for reading the frames in RGBA pixel format from `output.webm` file? I don't think Qt is relevant to your question (unless it is possible to capture the file using `QMediaPlayer`)... Do you want a workaround that uses FFmpeg CLI (FFmpeg command line interface) - reading the frames from `stdout` pipe of FFmpeg sub-process?

Comment: Yeah, Qt isn't relevant, but is good to mention where I want to put frames I read. Btw I don't like the workaround of using FFmpeg CLI, instead if the only way is to use FFmpeg directly I try to build it and include into my project and use it